# jQuery/Javascript minesweeper stacking lag issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, lag, minesweeper

I'm having some lag issues with my [minesweeper](http://patrikmarin.bugs3.com/Miinaharava/), and can't figure out what's causing this problem. The lag, however not disastrous one, stacks when more tiles are revealed (try it yourself!), so I've limited the possible sources for the lag to these couple functions:

```
function unhide(cell) { //called when user clicks a tile with class "hidden"
if ($(cell).hasClass('hidden')) {
    $(cell).removeClass('hidden');
    getclass(cell);
    if ($(cell).hasClass('miina')) {;
        locked = true;
        $('td').removeClass('hidden');
        textuncover();
        $('#endbox2').slideDown('slow');
        aika = null;
    }
    else if($(cell).hasClass('0')) {
        reveal(cell);
        revealmore();
    };
  };
};


function reveal(cell) { //if the clicked cell has no mines around it, the function reveals the mines the tile is touching
var row_crnt = $(cell).parent().parent().children().index($(cell).parent());
var cell_crnt = = $(cell).parent().children().index($(cell));
var row_new;
var cell_new;
if(row_crnt!=0) {
    row_new=miinakentta.rows[row_crnt -1];
    cell_new = row_new.cells[cell_crnt];
    $(cell_new).removeClass('hidden');
    getclass(cell_new);
};
if(row_crnt!=15) {
    row_new=miinakentta.rows[row_crnt +1];
    cell_new = row_new.cells[cell_crnt];
    $(cell_new).removeClass('hidden');
    getclass(cell_new);
};
if(cell_crnt!=0) {
    row_new=miinakentta.rows[row_crnt];
    cell_new = row_new.cells[cell_crnt -1];
    $(cell_new).removeClass('hidden');
    getclass(cell_new);
};
if(cell_crnt!=15) {
    row_new=miinakentta.rows[row_crnt];
    cell_new = row_new.cells[cell_crnt +1];
    $(cell_new).removeClass('hidden');
    getclass(cell_new);
};
if(row_crnt!=0 && cell_crnt!=0) {
    row_new=miinakentta.rows[row_crnt -1];
    cell_new = row_new.cells[cell_crnt -1];
    $(cell_new).removeClass('hidden');
    getclass(cell_new);
};
if(row_crnt!=15 && cell_crnt!=15) {
    row_new=miinakentta.rows[row_crnt +1];
    cell_new = row_new.cells[cell_crnt +1];
    $(cell_new).removeClass('hidden');
    getclass(cell_new);
};
if(row_crnt!=0 && cell_crnt!=15) {
    row_new=miinakentta.rows[row_crnt -1];
    cell_new = row_new.cells[cell_crnt +1];
    $(cell_new).removeClass('hidden');
    getclass(cell_new);
};
if(row_crnt!=15 && cell_crnt!=0) {
    row_new=miinakentta.rows[row_crnt +1];
    cell_new = row_new.cells[cell_crnt -1];
    $(cell_new).removeClass('hidden');
    getclass(cell_new);
};
};

function revealmore() { //makes all 'empty' tiles to reveal the content around it
var toreveal = $(".0:not(.hidden)");
if (toreveal.length != 0) {
    $(toreveal).each(function() { 
        getclass($(this));
        reveal($(this));
    });
setTimeout(revealmore,25);
};
toreveal = null;
};
```

I tried to combine the 'reveal' and 'revealmore' functions, but it didn't work out at all and caused even greater lag.

What should I do to decrease the amount of lag the user is suffering?

P.S Because I'm just practicing my js/jquery skills, the minesweeper works well only on Chrome and resolution around 1080p :)

Comment: Note Chrome has a performance profiler that I'd recommend using. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: Have you considered using a hash rather than forcing jQuery to scan the entire DOM for every hidden node? For example, you could maintain an object (var hidden = {}) and store all your hidden elements there relatively easily, saving you a lot of lookup time. In general, I would bet you'd have more efficient results if you stored state in objects versus DOM classes.

Comment: @RobertKotcher Thank you, I didn't now about that tool.

Comment: @mjk You're right, that would probably be good idea. I'll take a look!

Comment: @batupata I'm curious - did that help? Or did you find another possible optimization?